网上看到一名大三学生为推动中国劳动法进步在行凶前发布的公开信 Need help translate Chinese to English
Need help translate Chinese version of the perpetrator's public letter before committing the act to English version.
2024年11月16号发生了一起中国江苏无锡的一名大三学生持刀伤人的事件，导致8人死亡，还有17人受伤，起因是他在实习的时候，因忍受不了工厂每天生死轮回2班倒或3班倒，一天工作16个小时，一个月没有休息一天，这名学生因生病请几天假，部门经理竟然说别人发高烧的，流鼻血的都能干活，你凭什么不能，不能干就滚蛋，这名学生看到了工厂对工人无情的压榨与剥削，这名学生说工厂没有任何权力去罚人的款，这名学生用了很多办法却依然没办法解决，这名学生说他会为劳动者发声，这个世界需要被改变，一个人可以被毁灭但绝不能被打败，他宁可死也不愿再被压榨与剥削，他希望以他的死推动劳动法的进步。
下面是这名学生2024年11月16号在行凶前发布的公开信和中国警方的通报：
第一张图片：

第二张图片：

第三张图片：

第四张图片:

从第四张图片可以看到有人在2017年的时候在网上说过徐加金学校不给毕业证的问题，还建议高三学生不要报考这个学校。
第五张图片:

从第五张图片可以看到徐加金的理论成绩不差，只是不堪工厂用工单位的剥削，有不满和抗争才导致实操成绩不合格，而不是警情通报中所说的"考试不合格"，恰恰相反，考试是合格的，做人矿不合格。
不知道是否有人能帮忙把凶手在行凶前发布的公开信翻译为英文，当然这不是为我自己一个人服务，我感觉这是为了中国全体的劳工。
中华人民共和国劳动法规定 国家实行劳动者每日工作时间不超过八小时、平均每周工作时间不超过四十四小时的工时制度 来自 https://www.gov.cn/banshi/2005-05/25/content_905.htm 的 第四章　工作时间和休息休假 的 第三十六条 ，但实际情况是好多公司要求员工加班，有的公司是996工作制(see https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/996%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E5%88%B6)，好多工厂实行12小时2班倒工作制，也有3班倒，一周工作6天，有的工厂工作时间甚至高达一天16小时，这严重违反中国劳动法，希望大家共同努力呼吁中国劳动法的落实。
为了中国全体的劳工的权利，请大家不要投票关闭这个问题，谢谢。
补充一些信息：
或许有的人对行凶者在行凶前发布的公开信中以我的死推动劳动法的进步不理解，所以我补充一些信息。
先说事实：我之前一个关于法律方面的回答，结论就是在中国不讲法或者说中国实际生活中不按法律办事，具体见 https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/59181/36261
引用 新东方 创始人 俞敏洪在2013年7月26号说的话就是下面的图片：

个人的猜测如下：前几天2024年11月12号广东省汽车撞人事件导致35人死亡，43人受伤，这个事惊动了国家主席习近平，所以我猜测或许是徐加金 想以他的死亡(或死刑)引起国内外报道，使得大家关注，从而推动劳动法的进步。当然我不赞成这样伤及无辜的行为。又或许他想效仿2003年广东广州孙志刚事件吧，孙志刚的死使得废除了暂住证，当然了，徐加金持刀伤人这件事和孙志刚事件性质不一样。我只是猜测，根据徐加金行凶前的公开信应该是想达到类似孙志刚事件的效果，推动劳动法的进步。再次强调： 我不赞成这样伤及无辜的行为 。

Many people are willing to translate to and from all sorts of languages on https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/ - please post your request there.

Out of curiosity, how would you translate 我 in 以我的死推动劳动法的进步? 8 other people?

@dROOOze Thank you for website you provided.

@kyc 我认为应该翻译为I或者me，但我不确定用哪个，这个遗书的作者是徐加金.

@kyc Instead of reading word by word, you shall try to understand the phrase "以我的死".

@kyc I think user: r13 say is good, maybe can use my's dead or dead of my，但我不确定用哪个，记得这个遗书的作者是徐加金.

徐说要用他的死推动，实际上做的事却是杀了八个人。他脑子不正常，不明白什么是“我”的死也就算了，怎么还有人跟着说遗书、自杀什么的呢。我不想骂太难听所以说得委婉一点，没想到还被当外宾了。

@kyc 我已经修改了我的问题。估计是前几天2024年11月12号广东省汽车撞人事件导致35人死亡，43人受伤，这个事惊动了习近平，所以我猜测或许是他想以他的死亡(或死刑)引起国内外报道，使得大家关注，从而推动劳动法的进步。当然我不赞成这样伤及无辜的行为。或许他想效仿2003年广东广州孙志刚事件吧，孙志刚的死使得废除了暂住证，当然了，这件事和孙志刚事件性质不一样，我只是猜测，根据徐加金行凶前的公开信应该是想达到类似孙志刚事件的效果，推动劳动法的进步。再次强调： 我不赞成这样伤及无辜的行为 。

@kyc 关于”我不想骂太难听所以说得委婉一点，没想到还被当外宾了。“，请不要说脏话骂人，文明用语，这里也没有外宾内宾什么的，这里只有文明，让我们为构建文明社区而共同努力，大家互帮互助。

@kyc 关于说自杀的话，可能有争议，我是根据中东地区恐怖分子搞自杀式炸弹袭击的说法，恐怖分子这样搞不仅自己死，也连带别人一起死，所以中国国内的说法是自杀式炸弹袭击，觉得有争议的话我已经修改了我的问题，现在变成了行凶者在行凶前发布的公开信，这个性质和中东地区恐怖分子搞自杀式炸弹袭击差不多。

Try this: https://translate.google.com.tw/?sl=auto&tl=en&op=translate  ... if you are outside the wall.

@James OK, thank you for your link.


以我的死推动劳动法的进步

mr 徐’s logic is:

he would commit an severe crime (killing, hurting numerous people) after composing an open letter, put it online
he would be arrested
he would be prosecuted
he would got a death penalty by the court
he would be executed

so, “我的死” means my death [caused by death penalty]
next, the psychology of mass murderer could be summarised to 3 points:

struggling with mental health problems that have produced their desire to die
a deep sense of victimization and belief that the killer’s life has been ruined by someone else, who has bullied, oppressed or persecuted him
is the desire to acquire fame and glory through killing

Mass murderers want glory and fame. Somehow, we need to stop giving it to them

感谢你的答案，不过一个最重要的问题点是这封公开信是在他行凶前写的。

Such a text can be translated into understandable English by using any machine translator or online software or AI. It is easy.

It is interesting to note that two other infamous killers have the same middle name 加 like this one, namely, 马加爵who killed his college roommates and led to the most widespread manhunt ever in the 21st century,药加鑫who killed his teacher or somebody else in passion. Does that imply that like all rich guys having the surname of 马, all killers are a memeber of 加 family?

你说的关于"加"字，确实是个有意思的发现。另外 马云 和 马化腾 在中国都算富豪，关于 加 和 马 现象， 纯属巧合 ，他们之间没有任何实质性的关联。
